# CO₂ cylinder - aluminium vs steel, which one is preferred?

Tags: aquarium, fish, aquatic-plants

Folks, I'm planning to add pressurized CO<sub>2</sub> cylinder for my new tank. But now I'm stuck between the 2 cylinder materials: steel and aluminium:

- Steel is cheap, durable and heavy.
- Aluminium is a little costly and lightweight, not sure about durability.

I live in New Delhi, India. So, please suggest me a good option.

Comment: Do you mean that you're going to store the CO2 in the cylinder or that you're going to ferment bio mass and produce the CO2 inside it?

Comment: No, normal pressurized CO2.

Answer (score 1):

Get whatever is cheapest. Cylinders for aquariums experience almost zero wear since they're just sitting under an aquarium. No benefit in spending more on one for this purpose.

Comment: OK, is there any difference between steel and carbon steel?